# no such table: LTA_LONG_TABLES (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LTA_LONG_TABLES(longs,lat) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LTA_LONG_TABLES (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LTA_LONG_TABLES(longs,lat) VALUES (?,?)
```

How i solve it

[image]

[image]

This is logcat messages

```
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 161376 bytes, got 14480 
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 146896 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 130704 bytes, got 12768 
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 117936 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 101744 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.778 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 85552 bytes, got 3816 
07-15 04:47:32.782 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 81736 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.782 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 65544 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.782 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 49352 bytes, got 11056 
07-15 04:47:32.782 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 38296 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:32.782 356-357/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 22104 bytes, got 16192 
07-15 04:47:33.006 10645-10645/com.womansera.confession.mylatlong E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: LTA_LONG_TABLES
07-15 04:47:33.006 10645-10645/com.womansera.confession.mylatlong E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting longs=New Latitude: 28.613938333333333 lat=New Longitude: 77.20902
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   LTA_LONG_TABLES (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   LTA_LONG_TABLES(longs,lat) VALUES (?,?) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
>   at
>   com.womansera.confession.mylatlong.DbHelper.insertData(DbHelper.java:51)
>   at
>   com.womansera.confession.mylatlong.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:41)
>   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:234)
>   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:167)
>   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       07-15 04:47:33.066 10645-10645/com.womansera.confession.mylatlong E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 6528 bytes, got 2896

Comment: Please post text, not images! Furthermore, `no such table: LTA_LONG_TABLES` suggests that `LTA_LONG_TABLES` does not exist. Have you verified that it does exist or have you forgotten to create it?

Comment: try uninstalling the app and do a fresh install..

Comment: To update my comment, drop the quotes from `db.insert("LTA_LONG_TABLES" ...)`.

Comment: Try `db.insert(LTA_LONG_TABLES,null,contentValues);`

Answer (score 0):

While creating table try to add like,
db.execSQL("create table latlong"+ "(latitude text,longitude text)");

Hope this will help u.

Comment: Ok, then change the table name & re-install the app.